# Why is $A(\mathbb{T})\subset C(\mathbb{T})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

where $A(\mathbb{T})$ is the space of Absolutely Converging Fourier Series and $C(\mathbb{T})$ is the space of Continuous Functions, both over $\mathbb{T} = [0,1)$.

If $ f\in A(\mathbb{T})$ is $f\in C(\mathbb{T})?$

From the absolute convergence, one can prove the uniform convergence of the Fourier Series, thus the limit-function will be Continuous. But are we sure that the limit-function is f? We know that, if f is given Continuous. So I think that the result derives from something else, or I miss something about the Fourier Series and the corresponding function,

Comment: What are you assuming about $f$ to begin with? Are you assuming $f\in L^2$, $f\in L^1$ or some other condition entirely, such as $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: Nothing more, just that it is in $A$\mathbb{T})$. That's my question too.

Comment: I'd say that it is safe to assume $f\in L^1$ so that the Fourier coefficients exist. Fourier coefficients are unique in that case, meaning that, if $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, then $f=g$ a.e. iff the Fourier coefficients of $f$ equal the Fourier coefficients of $g$. In this case, every $f \in A(\mathbb{T})$ is equal a.e. to a periodic function $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: So somehow, we must involve quotients. I.e. $f\sim g$ then f=g a.e so f=g in $C(\mathbb{T})/{\sim}$. Then, with the assumption that f is integrable over $\mathbb{T}$, $f\in C(\mathbb{T})/{\sim}$ and $A(\mathbb{T})\subset C(\mathbb{T})/{\sim}$. Am I right? So, how is $C(\mathbb{T})$ connected to the quotient space $C(\mathbb{T})/{\sim}$?

Comment: To be more precise, $C(\mathbb{T})$ is Banach with the usual norm, is $C(\mathbb{T})/{\sim}$ Banach with the norm induced by the quotient map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an $f\in C^2(\mathbb{T})$. Then $f$ will obviously be continuous and its Fourier series will be absolutely convergent. Let 
$$ g(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ c l }
f(x),   &    x\in\mathbb{T}\setminus\{0\} \\
f(x)+1,   &    x=0
\end{array}
\right. $$
Then the Fourier series of $g$ will be the Fourier series of $f$ and thus will be absolutely convergent, but $g$ is not continuous. However, it is a.e. equal to a continuous function, which is the best you can achieve in general.

Answer (score 0):

Here $s_n f(x)$ is the $n$-th partial Fourier series of $f(x)$.

> **Fejer's theorem**
>   Let $f \in \mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{T})$.
>   Then $\sigma_n f(x) \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{} f(x)$ for all $x$ where $f$ is continuous. Moreover if $f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{T})$ then $\sigma_n f \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{\text{unif.}} f$ on $\mathbb{T}$.

Here $\sigma_n f(x) :=~ \frac{s_0 f(x) + ... + s_n f(x)}{n+1}$.

> Corollary 1 (Uniqueness theorem for $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{T})$ ) :  Let $f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{T})$. If $\widehat{f}(k) = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $f = 0$.
>
> Corollary 2 : Let $f \in \mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{T})$. If $s_n f(x) \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{} L$ and if $f$ is continuous at $x$ then $L = f(x)$.

That is to say if the limit at $x$ exists and if $f$ is continuous at $x$ then the limit is "the right one".